# Call get method from JS and return just string

Tags: javascript

I am not a JS developer and I have a simple question. I have an endpoint that returns a token as a string. I wrote this method

```
async function login() {
    let response = await fetch("generate");
    return response.data;
}

getUserToken: async function () {
        var token = login()
        console.log("token: "+ token)
        console.log("token.data: "+ token.data)
        console.log("token.body: "+ token.body)
        console.log("token.json(): "+ token.json())
        return token;
    }
```

And I have this log

```
token: [object Promise]
token.data: undefined
token.body: undefined
```

When I call this method in the browser I get my string: `fgfgxfgfgfgxcfg`

How can I get this string from JS?

Comment: Did you forget to await? `var token = await login()`?

Comment: I'm on the fence between answering and voting to close as a typo... You simply forgot to `await` the `async` function call.

Comment: @ crashmstr
 I added await - Uncaught (in promise) token value is not a string

Answer (score -2):

You're missing **await** keyword on **getUserToken** function.

Change your code to this:

```
async function login() {
    let response = await fetch("generate");
    return response.data;
}

async function getUserToken () {
        var token = await login()
        console.log("token: "+ token)
        console.log("token.data: "+ token.data)
        console.log("token.body: "+ token.body)
        console.log("token.json(): "+ token.json())
        return token;
}
```

Or you can do it better like this:

```
async function login() {
    let response = await fetch("your-api-endpoint");
    let text = await response.text();
    return text;
}

async function getUserToken () {
      try{
        var token = await login()
        console.log("token: "+ token);
        
        return token;
      }catch(err){
        console.log(`Error on fetch: ${err.message}`);
        return null;
      }
}
```